# Matrix table index SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two columns built from another table of names, one identity and one a name like this:

```
ID---Name
1----Mike
2----Jeff
3----Robert
...down to however many
```

Could be 10 rows, could be 100.  This will vary depending on input from other tables that are always changing but never be over 160 or so.

Now, pairings of names will have some meaning and thus a decimal data type score will be associated with said pairing (how at this point doesn’t matter, just need to build it for now...numbers just illustrative). I envision a matrix kind of like this:

```
ID------Name------Mike-------Jeff--------Robert-------- ...out to however many
1 -------Mike-------NULL------100.1------5.4-------- ...out to however many
2 -------Jeff---------100.1------NULL-----21.23--------- ...out to however many 
3 ------Robert-------5.4--------21.23-----NULL---------...out to however many
```

…down to however many happen to be in the first table…

Maybe this isn’t quite the most optimal way to go (Yes, I know there are duplicates in the table but I plan to structure the queries such that the duplicates are ignored) but at this point am not aware of many viable options.  After searching around, I thought maybe I wanted a pivot but that doesn’t seem to fit what I have here because I’m leaving the names in the column and associating them as column heads for a paired score.   Then I thought maybe I wanted to store a variable as the value of each row and then add them as the columns.  That was no help.  My latest iteration was maybe creating a temp table as an exact copy with and identity column, then trying to select the specific name by the identity and looping through them but I can’t even seem to grab the first name and make it a column name in addition to a row value under the name column...see below

```
--create a table of names with an identity column
CREATE TABLE myTable2
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Name VARCHAR(5),
);

--add names to the table from a different table
INSERT INTO myTable1  (Name)
SELECT Name
FROM myTable1 

--create a temp table with the same values
SELECT ID, Name
INTO #new
FROM myTable2
GROUP BY ID, Name

--insert name from first row as a column head
INSERT INTO myTable2 (SELECT Number FROM #new WHERE ID =1)
```

So, in the last bit there, INSERT INTO”, I want to copy the names, in this instance “Mike” and make it ALSO a column head in the same table where it is a row (like in my second table).  I get an error message that the syntax is not correct for the statement.  Why isn’t this allowed?  How can I get it to do what I want?  It also has been suggested by someone that knows way more about this stuff than me, that maybe instead of building the table as a matrix, build it as below.  It is possible here to get rid of the duplicates this way and I would except I have no idea where to even begin doing this…

```
Name1-----------Name2-----------Calculated Value
Mike--------------Mike-------------NULL
Jeff---------------Mike-------------100.1
Robert-------------Mike-------------5.4
Mike--------------Jeff-------------100.1
Jeff----------------Jeff-------------NULL
Robert------------Jeff-------------21.23
Mike--------------Robert-----------5.4
Jeff---------------Robert-----------21.23
Robert------------Robert-----------NULL
...etc
```

Any help suggestions or pointing of me in the right and most appropriate direction would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's how I solved my problem.  Looks like the Cartesian product was the way to go.  Thanks @Alex Kudryashev

```
--create a table of cross joined names
CREATE TABLE cartNames
(
Name1 VARCHAR(5),
Name2 VARCHAR(5),
);

--create two temporary tables from a source table of names
SELECT Name AS Name1
INTO #name1
FROM names
GROUP BY Name 

SELECT Name AS Name2
INTO #Name2
FROM names
GROUP BY Name 

--populate the Cartesian table
INSERT INTO cartNames
SELECT * FROM #name1 CROSS JOIN #name2

--get rid of the temp tables
DROP TABLE #Name1
DROP TABLE #Name2

--add columns and populate calculated scores
---
```

Comment: The last way is the way to go.  However, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I apologize.  I can’t get that last bit of the query to do what I want it to (i.e. put the name from the row on top of the next column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a **Cartesian Product**. There is very easy way to do so.

```
declare @tbl table(name varchar(10))
insert @tbl(name) values('MIke'),('Jeff'),('Robert')

select t1.name name1,t2.name name2, some_udf(t1.name,t2.name) calc_value
from @tbl t1 cross join @tbl t2
```

Comment: That just might get me the bottom output.  If so sir...plus one for you!  I’ll let ya know how it goes Monday and give you a check mark and upvote!!!!  I’ll also edit the title to include your wording.  Thanks again, kind sir!